# Table using Longtable/threeparttable/landscape in Scientific Workplace and Miktex

Tags: tables, scientific-workplace

I am really struggling with a situation where the following code of mine works in Miktex, but my colleague who uses Scientific Workplace gets the formatting completely wrong (in particular, the table note takes the entire page and is centered, and the caption writes ? in each page It's a real mess). Could anybody enlighten me on how to fix the code below? I am really lost here. :( I am aware of the similar posts and did read them all, but they do not help me fix up what's wrong with the below code. I will really appreciate a hand... thanks so much

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{threeparttablex,booktabs}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]
\item \small{Text Text Text.}
\end{TableNotes}
\medskip
{\small
\begin{longtable}{ | l c | c c c c c c | c |}
\caption{} 
\label{tab:Table jj} \\
\insertTableNotes 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{9}{c}
{ Table \thetable{} (continued) } \\ 
\endhead
\midrule
8888 & 360 (96) & 88886 & 88887.3 & 88880.8888 & 05.5 & 39.4 & 88880 & 66 \\
8888 & 888800 (75) & 88880.4 & 0.6 & 5.0 & 40.8888 & 88888888.0 & 6.7 & 36 \\
& 888860 (2222) & 7.6 & 7.8888 & 8888.5 & 88880.6 & 0.6 & 5.0 & 88889 \\
& 98888 (88884) & 6.0 & 6.4 & 8888.0 & 88886.9 & 7.7 & 5.5 & 88885 \\
& & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & \\
\midrule
\pagebreak
\midrule 
 8888 & 360 (96) & 988883XX & 888879XX & 8888.8888B & 88888888.6B & 747XX &    55XX & 66 \\
8888 & 888800 (75) & 300XX & 60XX & 788888888XX & 6.9B & 888868888XX & 88885XX & 36 \\
3 & 888860 (2222) & 888808888XX & 59XX & 336XX & 8888.9B & 888898888XX & 88888888XX & 88889 \\
4 & 98888 (88884) & 888835XX & 46XX & 888800XX & 8888.8888B & 888879XX & 88880XX & 88885 \\
5 & 30 (88880) & 08888XX & 43XX & 888808888XX & 488888888XX & 08888XX & 88885XX & 34 \\
& & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & \\
& & & & & & & & \\
\midrule
\end{longtable}}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Which version of Scientific Workplace does your coauthor use?

Comment: Mico, I will email and ask him. I will get back to you here. Do you see a problem with my code above, at all? (The table notes becomes totally centered in his compilation, taking the entire page, and the caption writes ?). Thanks for your prompt response and willingness to help by the way, debugging the table is totally confusing for me

Comment: For what it's worth, after I added the directives `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to your code, I was able to compile your example without experiencing any problems on my TeX system (MacTeX2016).

Comment: Mico, thanks a lot! By the way, could it be the case that one should not add threeparttable and threeparttablex packages at the same time? Or, could there be a situation where some other two packages should not be simultaneously added?

Comment: There are definitely cases where one shouldn't load any two given packages. However, that doesn't appear to be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe there is nothing to fix...the issue is that Scientific Workplace does NOT support all Latex features (for instance, multicolumns). It seems like longtable is another of those unsupported ones. And now that SWP publisher went out of business, I guess there is little chance those will be ever supported.

I had the same issue with one of my coauthors (I use Latex, he uses SWP), and spent long hours trying to fix it to no avail.